Modify the global variables in SolidWorks using Python script
I am trying to modify global variables in an existed part using python. The command that I'm using now is "model.GetEquationMgr()" but it doesn't work. I would appreciate if you can provide me with some assistance.
Best regards,
Amir
The command that I'm using now is "model.GetEquationMgr()" but it doesn't work.
